# Randomised 3-day golf groups for 12 players

Tags: mysql, unique

I started working on a CTE-based MySQL script for a small side project I have... and that is to determine, out of a group of 12 players, over 3 days, each group of 4 so that no plyer plays with the same player twice.  To explain further:

Day1. I would play with players 2, 3, and 4.

Day2. I would play with players 12, 11 and 10.

Day3. I would play with players 6, 7, and 8.

Naturally, these player ids would be randomised, but I hope you get the gist.

This would be also true for player 2.  Day1 they played with me, but Days2 and 3 they would have different people in their playing groups.

My code/thinking is far too basic - following these lines:

```
WITH Base_cte (select IDs of 12 people)
, D1T1 as (Select PlayerId, RAND() FROM Base Order by 2 LIMIT 4)
, D1T2 as (Select PlayerId, RAND() FROM Base (where not in D1T1) Order by 2 LIMIT 4)
, D1T3 as (Select PlayerId, RAND() FROM Base (where not in D1T1 or D1T2) Order by 2 LIMIT 4)
, 
SELECT 'Day1 Grp1' as Lbl, Player FROM D1T1 UNION 
SELECT 'Day1 Grp2', Player FROM D1T2 UNION 
SELECT 'Day1 Grp3', Player FROM D1T3
```

But this gives me a great Day1 - I am then lost for words to try Day2 onwards. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: As you are alluding to, blabla_bingo, defining the output required would have very quickly shown me it was impossble.  Thanks for looking into it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Constraints

- pool of 12 players
- over 3 days
- 3 groups of 4 players each day
- no player plays with the same player twice

If I have understood your rules correctly, you have given yourself an impossible task.

Consider the following three groups on "Day 1":

```
Day 1 Groups:
Group 1: ( 1,  2,  3,  4)
Group 2: ( 5,  6,  7,  8)
Group 3: ( 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

We cannot build a single group of 4 for "Day 2", let alone "Day 3".

Attempt to create "Day 2: Group 1"

```
Day 2 Groups:
Group 1: ( 1,  5,  9, ...)
```

1. We can take 1 from Day 1 Group 1
2. We can take 5 from Day 1 Group 2
3. We can take 9 from Day 1 Group 3
4. There is no fourth player to add, as every other player has already played with either 1, 5 or 9.

Based on your ruleset:

- You can build 4 groups of 3, from a pool of 12 players.
- You can build 4 groups of 4, from a pool of 16 players.
- But, you cannot build 3 groups of 4, from a pool of 12 players.

Comment: Until I eyeballed my own question, trying to prove you wrong (user1191247), I thought this was indeed possible.  But as you rightly say - an impossible task.  Thank you HEAPS for your efforts in making it really clear too.